# Using a condition with depends_on in docker compose results in nothing happening

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's my code:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  express:
    image: node:lts-alpine
    container_name: nodejs
    build:
      context: /
    command: npm run dev
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
      redis:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  database:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: ***
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  

  db-admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
```

After docker-compose is run it only completes up until `db-admin` and not `express` then stops there. HOWEVER if I manually run the `express` container in Docker Desktop it will start running. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

In case where your logic seems more complex to evaluate then better to have a script which will perform all validation and return true or false.

Add such script in images itself as utility scripts.

Comment: You mean like putting a line in the Dockerfile that checks to see if the port is available before running my seeds?

Comment: Dockerfile is consider while building image - so ADD instruction to embed your script in image. Then in docker-compose under depends_on section you can execute that check_script.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, so this check script would just check to see if the database port was ready??

Comment: you can have basic query - e.g. `select 1 from dual`; that gives value when database is ready to serve.

Comment: So am I correct? You're not really answering my question.

Comment: you (@Amon) are right.